# Is it possible to combine command-line options (switches) for similar commands?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, boolean-logic

At the Windows command prompt, typing `date /T & time /T` will output the date and time with command-line option `/T`.

> Time: If Command Extensions are enabled the TIME command supports the
>   `/T` switch which tells the command to just output the current time,
>   without prompting for a new time.
>
> Date: If Command Extensions are enabled the DATE command supports the
>   `/T` switch which tells the command to just output the current date,
>   without prompting for a new date.

`{date & time} /T` does not work. I want the /T switch to apply to both date and time commands, without having to type it twice.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.  You have to include the command-line options for each command.